# Logarithms: How to solve for $x$ in $(\sqrt{2}/2)^x = 2$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Need some help on how to approach problem.  My logs are rusty.

$$\log_{\sin45^\circ}2$$

I know that $\sin 45° = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.  So then the equation becomes $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^x = 2$.  How do I solve for $x$ in this case?

A step by step would be very helpful, thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is easier for you with $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So $\frac{x}{\log(1/\sqrt{2})}=\log(2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sin45^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=2^{-1/2}$, the answer is $\frac{1}{-1/2}=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Applying $\ln$, get $\ln({\sqrt2}/2)^x=\ln2\implies x\ln({\sqrt2}/2)=\ln2\implies x=\ln2/\ln({\sqrt2}/2)=1/\log_22^{-1/2}=1/(-1/2)=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$

so you want $x$ such that:
$$
\left(2^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^x=2^{-\frac{1}{2}x}=2
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \frac {\sqrt 2} 2 = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \\[15pt]
& \left( \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \right)^2 = \frac 1 2 \\[15pt]
& \left( \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \right)^{-2} = 2
\end{align}